# Change outer variable value inside library call

Tags: javascript, scope

I want to change the value of a variable which I'm calling in a library but it seems like due to some scope issue, I am not able to. My code looks like this:

```
var data = "";
abc.abc(lat, long).then(function(x) {
    data = x;
    console.log(data);
});
console.log(data);
```

The first output shows the value of x but the second output is still empty. What am I doing wrong?

Note: abc is an external library which uses promises.

Comment: The callback you pass to `.then()` is executed later, *after* the `console.log()` on the last line, at some point in the future after completion of whatever asynchronous process `.abc()` kicked off. That's kind of the point of promises...

Comment: So should I not use promises then? Any way to modify data?

Comment: No, you should use promises - and indeed you may not have any choice if that's how the external library works. But you need to structure your code in a way that whatever you want to do with the value is done inside the `.then()` callback (or in a function that you call from inside there).

Comment: Got it. I'm new to promises so wasn't sure how the callback works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to the value of `data` before it is assigned. Even though the inner `function(x)` is *declared* before the second `console.log` it is *called* after.

See a simplified illustration of *time* each statement is executed labeled next to the code, starting with time = 0

```
var data = ""; // time = 0
abc.abc(lat, long).then(function(x) {
    data = x; // time = N > 2 (i.e. at this time, the promise has been resolved)
    console.log(data);
}); // time = 1
console.log(data); // time = 2
```

Bottom line, if you Could refer to `data` synchronously this way then don't use a promise. However, not using promises for potentially long-running operations is NOT recommended.

You should adopt your code such that any Access to `data` happens only after the promise is resolved.

The best practice for doing so may differ according to the Javascript framework you are using (if any)

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure how promises work. Got it now. Restructuring my code now so that I can get this to work while using promises.

Answer (score 1):

it all about async programming, remember that promise is executed later after certain process is finished, so it is not blocking the IO to the user, you can use loading to tell the user that process is being executed.

```
var data = "";
//show loading
//block all input
abc.abc(lat, long).then(function(x) {
    data = x;
    console.log(data);
    // hide loading
    // continue the process
});
console.log(data);
```